# How do I set command line mode vga=788 permanently?

Tags: 10.10, server, command-line, grub2

I have a problem that is not of easy resolution, happen to tell...
 I have Installed Ubuntu 10.10 Server.
 I want to join to the system way vga=788, into the grub it changes without any problem   editing the file grub.cfg, the problem is that editing the above mentioned file I join to the system way vga=788 (800x600) and then command line puts itself in way vga=792 (1280x1024). 
 Is there any way of changing this configuration so that it is always vga=788?
tanks.
sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 2):

grub.cfg is an auto generated file, hence the big warning at the top that says not to edit it.  Instead you need to edit /etc/default/grub.

Comment: Good I was editing the file `/etc/default/grub` and changed `quiet` for `vga=788`
then 

    sudo update-grub 
    sudo reboot 

and the system continues of the same form. 
Anyway I think that the problem is in Framebuffer. 
tanks for answering so soon.